# How do I auto-indent new lines using a Windows 8 RichEditBox?

Tags: vb.net, windows-8

I have the following VB code to add a Tab character whenever the key is pressed within the RichEditBox, but I can't figure out how I can make it so when an end user presses the return key, the app will auto-indent so you wouldn't need to press the Tab key however many times to nest code correctly on each new line.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Current code for Tab insertion on KeyDown:

```
Private Sub TextBox_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyRoutedEventArgs) Handles TextBox.KeyDown
    If e.Key = Windows.System.VirtualKey.Tab Then
        e.Handled = True
        Dim SelectionText As String = ""
        TextBox.Document.Selection.GetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextGetOptions.None, SelectionText)
        TextBox.Document.Selection.TypeText(vbTab + SelectionText)
    End If
End Sub
```